# Upload file from ODI 12c linux server local directory to Oracle Object Storage folder

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage, oracle-data-integrator, cloud-object-storage

I have 20+ files that need to be uploaded using ODI 12c to different folders in an Oracle Object Storage bucket. The source files are in a folder in a Linux server where Oracle ODI 12c is running

I have mapped the Logical Schema pointing to the Object Storage Bucket root, is there a way to upload each file to its corresponding folder within the bucket? I tried creating a package and using OdiObjectStorageUpload which sends the file to the bucket root folder, but not to the specific folder where the file should be placed